# Telerik Radgrid Issue in Modal box ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Ragdrid in the Modal Box but it is not fetching any values on OnBatchEditCommand in the Radgrid that I populated from jquery.

Here's the code from which I populated the Radgrid

```
var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid2.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
tableView.set_dataSource(data);
tableView.dataBind();
```

The code where I am not getting values

```
 protected void RadGrid1_BatchEditCommand(object sender, GridBatchEditingEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridBatchEditingCommand command in e.Commands)
            {
                Hashtable oldValues = command.OldValues;
                Hashtable newValues = command.NewValues;
}
}
```

Comment: If you can, try to bind with the NeedsDataSource event. The issue could be due to the fact that the event is intended to be used with server side binding: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/server-side-programming/events/batcheditcommand

Comment: By using the NeedsDataSource event on the server side. I am getting the empty Radgrid inside Modal Box.